# Algorithm for finding shortest path between 2 objects

Tags: algorithm, d3.js, shortest-path

I have a floorplan with lots of d3.js polygon objects on it that represent booths. I am wondering what the best approach is to finding a path between the 2 objects that don't overlap other objects. The use case here is that we have booths and want to show the user how to walk to get from point a to b the most efficient. We can assume path must contain only 90 or 45 degree turns.

we took a shot at using Dijkstra but the scale of it seems to be getting away from us.

The example snapshot of our system:

[image]

Our constraints are that this needs to run in the browser. Would be nice if it worked well with d3.js.

Comment: How exactly did Dijkstra not work for you here? I can't see how the problem, given its description, would give Dijkstra any trouble. If what you mean is that it's too slow, then there has to be an inefficient implementation. Even for graphs containing hundreds of nodes, Dijkstra should give you decent performance.

Comment: Can people climb over the booths?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the layout is a matrix (or nested matrices) this is not a Dijkstra problem, it is simpler than that. The technical name for the problem is a "Manhatten routing". Rather than give a code algorithm, I will show you an example of the optimum route (the blue line) in the following diagram. From this it should be obvious what the algorithm is:
[image: Manhatten route]
Note that there is a subtle nuance here, and that is that you always want to maximize the number of jogs because even though the overall shape is a matrix, at each corner the person will actually walk diagonally (think of a person cutting diagonally across a four-way intersection). Therefore, simply going north, then west is wrong, because you would only get to cut one corner, but on the route shown you get to cut 5 corners.

Comment: Awesome man. Really simple way of looking at this, thanks for the help.

Comment: This is wrong answer, may be this get good dub optimal way, but it does not get best way, is not necessary to have rectilinear path. counter example is easy to draw but not easy to describe (I think you can imagine at least one counter example). This problem as I mentioned in my answer is very famous and is not as easy as you wrote. Anyway using Dijkstra on underling graph is not time consuming.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is known as finding shortest path between two points with polygonal obstacle, and studied a lot in literature. See [here](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/labs/theory/thread/papers/short.pdf) for one example. All algorithms for this is by converting problem to the graph theory problem then running Dijkstra. To doing this:

1. Each vertex in any polygon is vertex in your graph.
2. Start point and end points are also vertices in the graph.
3. Between two vertex there is an edge, if they are visible to each other, to achieve this we can use triangulation algorithms.
4. Weight of each edge is the distance between its two endpoints in Euclidean space.

Now we are ready to run any shortest path algorithm. The hard part is triangulation, I think [triangle](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html) library fits for your requirements. Also easier way is searching the web by the keywords that I said in the first line to find implementation. I didn't link to any implementation because I see is better to say it in algorithmic manner to be useful to the future readers.